# Showing current time in Android and updating it?

Tags: android, time, textview

I want to display current time and keep it updating, in this format example: **09:41**  Hour:Minute. Is it possible to do in `TextView`? I tried some ways but I'm not getting what I actually want.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick

```
final Handler someHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());   
        someHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tvClock.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.US).format(new Date()));
                someHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        }, 10);
```

You should keep a reference to the handler and the runnable to cancel this when the `Activity` goes to pause and resume when it resumes. Make sure you remove all callbacks to handler and set it to `null` in `onDestroy`

Comment: Hey one last question! How to set it to 12 hour format?

Comment: @BojanKseneman thank you mate, none example worked for me as I wanted the same solution for Service class, but your code worked for me like a charm!

Comment: Instead of SimpleDateFormat, you might also use android.text.format.DateUtils.

Comment: TextClock allows to do same thing - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock

Answer (score 22):

Android has a view for this already.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html

You can use it directly in XML like so

```
<TextClock
    android:id="@+id/textClock"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
```

It is min api 17, so you if need to go lower than that just look into

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DigitalClock.html

Worst case scenario you can subclass textview and steal the code from the textclock source. it should be fairly straightforward

Comment: Can you show me example? I'll rapidly accept your answer!

Comment: there is literally nothing to it. It is actually a subclass of textview and it does everything for you. just click and drag it into the layout in the xml designer

Comment: But it requires API 17!

Comment: I found solution:
Date d = new Date();
CharSequence s = DateFormat.format("hh:mm", d.getTime());
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
tv.setText(s);
 
But how to update this time? Just tell this much!!! Please!!!

Comment: the other answer will show you how to update it manually. but you'd be much better off using the classes google made for this purpose rather than updating it yourself

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76575/discussion-between-user2635995-and-ajinkya-more).

Comment: @AjinkyaMore my answer explains how to update the text view at a set interval. If you still need help, just use it as reference.

Answer (score 3):

```
  boolean run=true; //set it to false if you want to stop the timer
  Handler mHandler = new Handler();


 public void timer() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (run) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(20000);
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                                int min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                                int hour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                                TextView.setText(String.valueOf(hour)+":"+String.valueOf(min));
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();}
```

in the onCreate call it like this

```
  timer();
```

Comment: Should I call timer(); before `setContentView` ?

Comment: no beacuase the timer needs to find the textView .. so it my rise NullPoiterException ..call it efter setContentView

Comment: and set the updating time as you like here in my code it is 20 seconds "20000"

Comment: I want to update text clock time in background service then how it is possible?

Answer (score 3):

For someone who needing a custom date and time directly by using `TextClock`

- Format for time: `android:format12Hour="hh:mm:ss a"`
- Format for date:  `android:format24Hour="MMM dd, yyyy"`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_screenlock"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <TextClock
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/_white"
            android:textSize="70sp"
            android:format12Hour="hh:mm:ss a"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextClock
            android:id="@+id/textDateTime"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/_white"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:format24Hour="MMM dd, yyyy"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


[![date_time_update_directly][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZWUj.png
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use Java's Timer and TimerTask? They're very easy, reliable and simple to understand.

Here is an example:

```
public class ClockCounter extends TimerTask{

    private long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    @Override
    public void run(){
        time += 1000; //add 1 second to the time
        //convert ms time to viewable time and set MainActivity.text (textview) text to this.
    }

    public long getTime(){ return time; }
}

public class MainActiviy extends Activity{

    public static TextView text;
    private Timer timer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        //default code
        //set text view according to id
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new ClockCounter(), 0, 1000); //schedule clock counter to repeat every 1 seconds (1000 ms)
    }
}
```

I know there are some notes of what to do in there but any android developer with reasonable experience in Java should be able to figure out how to do those things.

I hope this helped!

**EDIT**
To format the date to a viewable string, you can use the following code (also using only Java's shipped APIs)

```
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm"); //Hourse:Minutes
String dateFormatted = formatter.format(date); //string representation
```

Comment: Android is not a realtime OS so you can't rely that it will be exactly 1000ms when the next timer cycle is called and you are integrating the error over time you make in each step :/

Answer (score 1):

For getting time and date you can use Calender class

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
String time = ""+cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Comment: Just as a side note: when developing android app under Android Things, calendar API will not be accessible.