# Does not implement inherited abstract member Java.Util.TimerTask Error

Tags: android, inheritance, xamarin, timertask

I have this code but I have also this error:

Does not implement inherited abstract member Java.Util.TimerTask

```
namespace App21
{
    class DTime :TimerTask
    {
        private long time = Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis();
        public void run()
        {
            time += 1000; //add 1 second to the time
        }
        public long getTime() 
        {
            return time; 
        }
    }
}
```

I saw [Showing current time in Android and updating it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29952404/showing-current-time-in-android-and-updating-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `override` keyword on the Run method, also this method has the "R" in capital, remember Xamarin is C#.

Change you implementation to this:

```
public class DTime : TimerTask
{
    private long time = Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis ();

    public DTime ()
    {

    }

    public override void Run ()
    {
        time += 1000;
    }

    public long GetTime ()
    {
        return time;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you apineda. How can I see hour, minute and second in a textview ? `Java.Util.Timer timer = new Java.Util.Timer(); timer.Schedule(new DTime(), 0, 1000);`