# Dynamic time display crash on orientation

Tags: nullpointerexception, calendar, crash, orientation

I have a layout that will display a `TextView` which is used to display a ticking time.I followed the codes from this link

[How to Display current time that changes dynamically for every second in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634231/how-to-display-current-time-that-changes-dynamically-for-every-second-in-android)

but I get an error of

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

I had the same problem here but I fixed it

[Intent extras null on configuration change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38757374/intent-extras-null-on-configuration-change?noredirect=1#comment64889190_38757374)

Here are the Java codes

```
void clockTicking(){
final CountDownTimer newtimer = new CountDownTimer(1000000000, 1000) {

  public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    timeDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTime);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    timeDisplay.setText(c.get(Calendar.HOUR)+":"+c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+":"+c.get(Calendar.SECOND)+" PM");
  }
  public void onFinish() {
  }
};
newtimer.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code **timeDisplay** object is null.

Make sure your textview id is correct. Double check this line `timeDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTime);`

I think your id **txtTime** is incorrect.

Hope it will helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I'm pretty sure my `TextView` id is correct because that's the only variable I use to display anything.If it did not exist then Android Studio would surely detect it.But to be safe I still checked if it was correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I finally fixed it,the only reason why it crashed was because during orientation the layout I used has no **TextView** which **Mitesh Vanaliya** stated was correct.So I fixed it by turning it off upon orientation using this code thanks to **Ayyappan** from

[How to Display current time that changes dynamically for every second in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634231/how-to-display-current-time-that-changes-dynamically-for-every-second-in-android)

Turning off the clock

```
void clockUnTicking(){
CountDownTimer newtimer = new CountDownTimer(1000000000, 1000) {

  public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    timeDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTime);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    timeDisplay.setText(c.get(Calendar.HOUR)+":"+c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+":"+c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
  }
  public void onFinish() {

  }
};
newtimer.cancel();
}
```

to turn it on just replace `newtimer.cancel();` with `newtimer.start()`