# ANDROID - How to display datetime that already passed?

Tags: java, android, datetime, duration, period

I want to display the time that already passed with specific time and date.

Example :

```
time1 = 2017-06-18 07:00:00 //set time
curtime = 2017-06-19 07:00:01 //get the current time
```

`TextView` will just display `0 Years 0 Month 1 Days 00 Hours 00 Minutes 01 Seconds already passed_`

If someone have the best keyword for me to finding my self, I appreciate it.

Ref: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634231/how-to-display-current-time-that-changes-dynamically-for-every-second-in-android) but not enough to face my issue.

Comment: Please share the code that you have come up with so far.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18719181/3395198

Comment: @Sufian i'm notyet type the code because i'm stuck from where should i start

Comment: @dreq use `compareTo`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya are you sure the link given is dynamically? because im comparing specific time with current time

Comment: @dreq please do some search and put some effort in solving the question. You will find some questions very similar to what you're trying to achieve. Please also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya the link given is just displaying if date1 is higher or lower then date2, but i need more result like `10-2=8` and not like `10-2=10 is bigger then 2`

Comment: @Sufian thans for the suggesting, but as you see above, i've tried to find the tutorial about my issue, but till now i got nothing

Comment: @dreq the link you gave is for count down timer, but your question is a bit simple. If you show the code that you've worked out, it will help us understand where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the difference between 2 dates, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, there's the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

First I parsed the strings to a `LocalDateTime` object, then I've got the difference between those dates. The API has created 2 different concepts of "time-difference/amount of time": a `Period`, a date-based amount of time (in terms of years, months and days), and a `Duration`, a time-based amount (in terms of seconds).

```
import org.threeten.bp.Duration;
import org.threeten.bp.LocalDate;
import org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime;
import org.threeten.bp.LocalTime;
import org.threeten.bp.Period;
import org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter;

String time1 = "2017-06-18 07:00:00"; // set time
String curtime = "2017-06-19 07:00:01"; // get the current time

// parse the strings to a date object
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime t1 = LocalDateTime.parse(time1, fmt);
LocalDateTime cur = LocalDateTime.parse(curtime, fmt);

// get the period between the dates
LocalDate startDate = t1.toLocalDate();
LocalDate endDate = cur.toLocalDate();
Period period = Period.ZERO;
if (startDate != null && endDate != null) {
    period = Period.between(startDate, endDate);
}

// get the duration between the dates
LocalTime startTime = t1.toLocalTime();
LocalTime endTime = cur.toLocalTime();
startTime = startTime != null ? startTime : LocalTime.MIDNIGHT;
endTime = endTime != null ? endTime : LocalTime.MIDNIGHT;
Duration duration = Duration.between(startTime, endTime);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
append(sb, period.getYears(), "year");
append(sb, period.getMonths(), "month");
append(sb, period.getDays(), "day");
long seconds = duration.getSeconds();
long hours = seconds / 3600;
append(sb, hours, "hour");
seconds -= (hours * 3600);
long minutes = seconds / 60;
append(sb, minutes, "minute");
seconds -= (minutes * 60);
append(sb, seconds, "second");

System.out.println(sb.toString()); // 1 day 1 second

// auxiliary method
public void append(StringBuilder sb, long value, String text) {
    if (value > 0) {
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        sb.append(value).append(" ");
        sb.append(text);
        if (value > 1) {
            sb.append("s"); // append "s" for plural
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

> 1 day 1 second

---

Note that the `Period` class already keeps the fields (years, months and days) separated, while the `Duration` class keeps only the seconds (so some calculations are needed to get the correct results) - it actually has methods like `toHours()`, but it only converts the seconds to hours, and it doesn't separate all the fields like we want.

You can customize the `append()` method to the exact format you want. I just took the simple approach of printing `value + text`, but you can change it according to your needs.

---

## Java new Date/Time API

For Java >= 8, there's the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). You can use this new API and the [ThreeTen Extra project](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/), which has the `PeriodDuration` class (a combination of both `Period` and `Duration`).

The code is basically the same as above, the only difference is the packages names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

```
import org.threeten.extra.PeriodDuration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

String time1 = "2017-06-18 07:00:00"; // set time
String curtime = "2017-06-19 07:00:01"; // get the current time

DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime t1 = LocalDateTime.parse(time1, fmt);
LocalDateTime cur = LocalDateTime.parse(curtime, fmt);

PeriodDuration pd = PeriodDuration.between(t1, cur);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
append(sb, pd.getPeriod().getYears(), "year");
append(sb, pd.getPeriod().getMonths(), "month");
append(sb, pd.getPeriod().getDays(), "day");
long seconds = pd.getDuration().getSeconds();
long hours = seconds / 3600;
append(sb, hours, "hour");
seconds -= (hours * 3600);
long minutes = seconds / 60;
append(sb, minutes, "minute");
seconds -= (minutes * 60);
append(sb, seconds, "second");

System.out.println(sb.toString()); // 1 day 1 second
```

Of course you can also create a `Period` and a `Duration` using the same code of `org.threeten.bp`'s version.

Comment: thanks for detail function and the code, i'll read the doc you given above, :)

Answer (score 1):

Check DateUtils:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString(long,long,long)

Should give you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `Date` objects of `Calendar` objects and compare them to know how much time has passed.

Or you can use the `Joda` date time library to find it.

[Check out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12852021/1055241)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) and [`java.time.Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) which were introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html) to model [ISO_8601#Durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations). With *Java-9*, some more convenience method were added.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-M-d H:m:s", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDateTime startDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2017-06-18 07:00:00", dtf);

        // Use the following line for the curren date-time
        // LocalDateTime endDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(); 

        // Use the following line for a given end date-time string
        LocalDateTime endDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2017-06-19 07:00:01", dtf);

        Period period = startDateTime.toLocalDate().until(endDateTime.toLocalDate());
        Duration duration = Duration.between(startDateTime, endDateTime);

        // ############################ Java-8 ############################
        String periodDuration = String.format("%d Years %d Months %d Days %02d Hours %02d Minutes %02d Seconds",
                period.getYears(), period.getMonths(), period.getDays(), duration.toHours() % 24,
                duration.toMinutes() % 60, duration.toSeconds() % 60);
        System.out.println(periodDuration);
        // ############################ Java-8 ############################

        // ############################ Java-9 ############################
        periodDuration = String.format("%d Years %d Months %d Days %02d Hours %02d Minutes %02d Seconds",
                period.getYears(), period.getMonths(), period.getDays(), duration.toHoursPart(),
                duration.toMinutesPart(), duration.toSecondsPart());
        System.out.println(periodDuration);
        // ############################ Java-8 ############################
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0 Years 0 Months 1 Days 00 Hours 00 Minutes 01 Seconds
0 Years 0 Months 1 Days 00 Hours 00 Minutes 01 Seconds
```

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).